# How to Escape Specific Characters Multiple Times in a String Using Java

Tags: java

I have an array of special characters like the following

```
String[] special = {
        "\", ":", "/"
    };
```

What I want to be able to do is loop through a `given` string and if I encounter any of the characters in the `special` array, I want to add an escape `\\` in front of that character. Please see the following input below

```
Input: Hello : Good : Day
Output Hello \\: Good : Day
Expected: Hello\\:Good\\:Day
```

As you can see, after it sees the first instance of a `special` character, it does not check for any other. Any help is appreciated. Code is below

```
 String[] special = { "\", ":", "/" };

   public String specialCheck(String replaceMe) {

        String cleanMe = replaceMe.replace(" ", "");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(cleanMe);

        for (String badChars : special) {
            if (cleanMe.contains(badChars)) {
                stringBuilder.insert(cleanMe.indexOf(badChars) , "\\\\");
            }
        }

    return stringBuilder.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible answer to your problem.

I made it only using Strings and ArrayLists and it is as simple as possible (Even dumb lol, but it's working).

I don't use StringBuilders because they are mutable and for the case, they are difficult to handle.

Improve it as you wish (**I am not using replace(" ", "") by the way), but I saw you may want to use it.** Regards.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(specialCheck("Hello : Good : Day / Test $ for : the @ problem"));
    }


    public static String specialCheck(String replaceMe) {
        String[] special = { "\\", ":", "/", "$", "@"};

        ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> phrase = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < replaceMe.length(); i ++) {
            phrase.add(String.valueOf(replaceMe.charAt(i)));
            for(int j = 0; j < special.length; j++) {
                if(String.valueOf(replaceMe.charAt(i)).equals(special[j].toString())) {
                    positions.add(i);   
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < phrase.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < special.length; j++) {
                if(phrase.get(i).equals(special[j])) {
                    phrase.remove(i);
                    phrase.add(i, "\\\\" + special[j] );
                }
            }
        }

        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < phrase.size(); i++) {
            result = result + phrase.get(i);
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Result for the test I made:
**Hello \\: Good \\: Day \\/ Test \\$ for \\: the \\@ problem**

Answer (score 2):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="Hello : Good : Day";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(":", "\\\\\\\\:"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello \\: Good \\: Day
```

**Note:**

1. Use `String:replaceAll` to replace all occurrences.
2. Use `\\` to escape `\`

**[Update]**

Posting the following update based on OP's comment:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getEscapedString("Hello : Good : Day"));
        System.out.println(getEscapedString("Hello / Good / Day"));
        System.out.println(getEscapedString("Hello \\ Good \\ Day"));
    }

    static String getEscapedString(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("[:/\\\\]+", "\\\\\\\\$0");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello \\: Good \\: Day
Hello \\/ Good \\/ Day
Hello \\\ Good \\\ Day
```

Comment: But I have an array of characters. I want to replace those characters also not just the `:`. Please see updated code.

Comment: @CodeMonkey So do it in a loop?

Comment: @CodeMonkey - I've posted an update. It fulfils this requirement i.e. it will replace all of your special characters (`:`,  `/`, and \\) in the string. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = replaceMe

for( i = 0 ; i < special.length ; i ++)
      result = result.replaceAll(special[i], "////" + special[i]);
```